# If a set contains more vectors than there are entries in each vector, then the set is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

If a set contains more vectors than there are entries in each vector, then the set is linearly dependent. Can anyone please explain this property in an easy-to-understand manner (with visualization if that helps).

Comment: think about this in $\mathbb{R}^2$: draw three vectors, can they be independent?  Take two out of three of these vectors, if they are one a multiple of the other, they are dependent and so also all three are. If they are not, they they span all $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so also the third vectors

Comment: Does it mean that the third vector can always be expressed as a function of the other two vectors combined?

Comment: If you followed my edit of the comment you will see that if you choose the two at random you can fail but if you choose the two carefully then yes (also when talking about linearly dependency we are not talking about a function in general but a linear one)

Comment: The fact that it is mentioned 'set contains more vectors' rules out any occurrence of dependency such as (2,4), (4,8), as then both (2,4), (4,8) are similar or one vector. So this statement (if a set contains more vectors than there are entries in each vector, then the set is linearly dependent) is when none of the three data sets are multiples of each other in the case of 2 dimensions.